# Relationship between zero-coupon bond price and interest rate

Tags: fixed-income, interest-rates

Let $P$ be the zero-coupon bond price, $R$ be interest rate and $t$ be the time to maturity of the bond, is it true that $$P = \frac{1}{1+R*t}?$$

I read this from my professor's lecture notes. How do we derive this formula between zero-coupon bond price and interest rate?

Comment: Looks like a (simplified) formula for Tbills, i.e. zero coupon securities with 1 year or less to maturity. So $0<t \le 1$. It would not be correct for longer term ZCB. You don't derive it, it is a definition (or assumption).

Comment: @nbbo2 It is taught in a FX course. On the slides, it is written as $$P = \frac{1}{1+R*(ACT/360)}$$ where ACT is days $< 360$. I think $(ACT/360)$ can be represented as $t$, so I used $t.$

Comment: Yeah, that looks correct and familiar. Basic money market stuff, with typical 360 day per year convention. I could have said "money market zero coupon securities" rather than tbills to be more general.